# How is floating point implemented in 32 and 64 bit processors?

Tags: floating-point, processor

I'm really confused  with this. Can someone kindly explain to me how floating point is implemented with a 32 and 64 bit processor?

ThankYou

Comment: Can you be more specific ? What do you mean by "a 32 and 64 bit processor" ?

Comment: I'm sorry, I really don't know. I have a task of describing how floating point effects the processor or how it's implemented within the processor. I'm sorry that I cannot be more specific, I'm really confused myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read the IEEE specification wikipedia is a starter:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point

Basically they are just an array of bits that represent the number.

```
First bit:          The sign
Second to n-th bit: The exponent
n-th + 1 to end:    The fraction
```

(You have to learn binary math to know how it works)

[image]

The `n-th` varies on the precision needed, the exponent and the fraction grows as the precision needed is bigger. The difference between processors are:

"Can the processor and BUS compute in one cycle?"; if it can't, the number is allocated in more than one position on memory -> bus -> cache -> processor (it is processed by pieces), hence, the number is processed in 2 cycles or more. For example, a 64 bit number is processed in two cycles in a 32 bit computer and in 1 cycle in a 64 bit computer. This is because the size in memory, bus, cache and processor are bigger in a 64 bit computer.